# Numba AOT compilation not working with numpy functions

Tags: python, numpy, compilation, numba, aot

I am trying to compile some code using numba AOT, but I seem to always encounter the same problem every time numpy is involved. Here are 2 examples of that:

```
@cc.export('sum', 'i4(f8, f8)')
def sum(x, y):
    array = np.arange(x * y).reshape(x, y)
    sum = 0
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y):
            sum += array[i, j]
    return sum
```

and

```
@cc.export('VolumeTetrahedra', 'f8(f8[:], f8[:], f8[:], f8[:])')
def VolumeTetrahedra(a, b, c, d) :
    V = abs(1/6*np.linalg.det(np.concatenate([np.stack([a,b,c,d]).T, np.array([1,1,1,1]).reshape(1,-1)])))
    return V
```

Both of these functions fail to compile, but I don't know why, this is all I can see:
[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExePm.png)

Is there anything I am missing? Also, I know pure numpy won't get faster using Numba, but I am only using this as an example of a bigger project I am trying to do for the sake of this questions. My bigger project has lots of functions that interact with numpy functions but are not only numpy functions. I am using numba 0.54.1 installed via Conda on windows computer if that helps.

Comment: For completeness I will repeat what I said in the other question. If I add from `numba.pycc import CC; cc = CC('my_module')` both compile fine on my mac running numba 0.54.0 and numpy 1.20.3. Maybe something went wrong with your installation?